# Error: InvalidRibbonDefinition when Disabling Ribbon Items in Word Web Add-in using Office.js and Angular

Tags: office-js, office-addins, word-addins

I'm working on a Word Web Add-in using Office.js and Angular, and I'm trying to programmatically enable and disable ribbon items within my add-in. According to the Microsoft Office Add-ins documentation, I should be able to use the Office.ribbon.requestUpdate method to update ribbon elements.
Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/design/disable-add-in-commands

```
 Office.ribbon.requestUpdate({
      tabs: [
        {
          id: 'TabCustom',
          groups: [
            {
              id: 'TabGroup2',
              controls: [
                {
                  id: 'Btn1',
                  enabled: false,
                },
              ],
            },
          ],
        },
      ],
    });
```

while executing above code I'm getting the error:

```
Error: Uncaught (in promise): InvalidRibbonDefinition: InvalidRibbonDefinition
RichApi.Error: InvalidRibbonDefinition
```

I've verified that the IDs in my code match the IDs in the manifest file. What could be causing this "InvalidRibbonDefinition" error, and how can I resolve it?

Office.js Version: CDN "https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/office.js"
Angular Version: 16.2.0

Thank you for your assistance.

Ribbon button should be enable or disabled programmatically.